# psql asking for user password and even tho i provide correct password it returns error

Tags: postgresql, command-line, psql

I am taking CS50 Web Programming course and after installing PostgreSQL i had issues with setting path for psql, after overcoming that i tried to run psql and i am being asked for password which i figured is the one i set when installing PostgreSQL. I was looking for an answer for a long time now and haven't found anything that worked. I am using Windows 10 and PostgreSQL 12.

Command line paste after trying to run it in admin mode:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>psql 
>   Password for user Korisnik: 
>   psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Korisnik"

Comment: The default user for a postgres installation is usually 'postgres' - I'd suggest trying that user with the password you set at installation.

Comment: How do i do that ?

Comment: When you open up psql, should be prompted for a username, enter 'postgres'. If you're not then running psql using "psql -U postgres" should do it

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir. It did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering so this can be marked as answered:

Default username for PostgreSQL installations is typically postgres.

Therefore when prompted to enter a username enter 'postgres' or if there is no prompt to enter a username run psql using the following command to specify the username.

```
psql -U postgres
```